# List returns value none within code

Tags: python, list

creates variable sin order for me to recall them later.

```
def initialise():
    global num
    global neg
    global pos
    global pos_list
    global neg_list
    global pos_sum
    global neg_sum
    pos_sum=0
    neg_sum=0
    num=1
    neg=0
    pos=0
    pos_list=[]
    neg_list=[]
    print("type your numbers")
    listing()

                                                                                                                                                            Allows the user to repeatedly list positive or negative numbers until they use '0'                    
def listing():
    global num
    global neg
    global pos
    global pos_list
    global neg_list
    global neg_sum
    global pos_sum
    num=1
    try:
        num=float(input())
        float(num)
        if num<0:
            neg_list.append(num)
            neg+=1
            neg_sum+=num
            listing()
        elif num>0:
            pos_list.append(num)
            pos+=1
            pos_sum+=um
            listing() 
        else:
            end()
    except ValueError:
        listing()
```

this ends the code and creates a simple table for the user to view.(I always make tables like this as I find it easier this way and I know there are table functions but I am at school and they do not have the necessary libraries

```
def end():
    global pos_list
    global neg_list
    global neg_sum
    global pos_sum
    global neg
    global pos
    pos_list=pos_list.sort()
    neg_list=neg_list.sort()
    total_sum=pos_sum+neg_sum
    print(" "*33,"Positive"," "*(50-len('positive')),"Negetive"," "*(50-len('negetive')))
    i1=0
    i2=0
    if len(pos_list)>=len(neg_list):
        count=len(pos_list)
    elif len(pos_list)<len(neg_list):
        count=len(neg_list)
    else:
        pass
    for x in range(count):
        print("number"," "*(50-len('number')-len(count)),pos_list[i1]," "*(50-len(pos_list[i1])),neg_list[i2]," "*(50-len(neg_list[i2])))
        i1+=1
        i2+=1
    print("amount of numbers"," "*(50-len('amount of numbers')),pos," "*(50-len(pos)),neg," "*50-len(neg))
    print("total"," "*(50-len('total')),pos_sum," "*(50-len(pos_sum)),neg_sum," "*(50-len(neg_sum)))

initialise()
```

the problem:

```
NameError: global name 'pos_list' is not defined
```

occurs here:

```
if len(pos_list)>=len(neg_list):
```

but I can see this happening 3-4 lines after as well.

Comment: Your error does not seem to match the code you post. I have tried to reproduce this but cannot. I have written a function that starts with `global pos_list` and this is enough to make the name defined and not produce the error.

Comment: I also copied your code and tested it successfully.  with the exception of the mistyped variable `um` inside of `def listing()` which I fixed in my sample, everything seemed to work as expected.  I did not get the error you are referring to.